# = not being read Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to get the wifi password with a batch file but one command is not being read correctly (my interpretation).

```
Netsh WLAN show profile name= %WifiName% key='clear'
```

turns into

```
Netsh WLAN show profile name= %WifiName% key 'clear'
```

when run in

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('Netsh WLAN show profile name= %WifiName% key="clear"') do ^
echo "%%i"
```

If you need more information ill give it but I'm too stupid to think of any right now.

entire code

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%i in ('Netsh WLAN show profile') do ^
set WifiName=%%i

Netsh WLAN show profile name= %WifiName% key='clear'

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('Netsh WLAN show profile name= %WifiName% key"=""clear"') do ^
echo "%%i"


pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `=` in the `for` loop. Here is a working example for you.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2*delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile ^|find /i "All User Profile"') do (
    for /f "tokens=2*delims=:" %%i in ('netsh wlan show profile name^=%%a key^=clear ^| findstr /C:"Key Content"') do echo Wifi: %%a pass: %%i
)
```

As you can see by my example, the second `for` is being run for each metavariable from the previous `for`. In your example (though not working) you set all the variables and only the last one is being used.